# Add a button to Windows 8 Quick Access Toolbar which will rename only selected files

Tags: windows-8, automation, ribbon, file-rename

While working throughout the day, I have to manually rename files adding "_Final" to the end of the file's name. I do this quite literally hundreds of times per day and while it's a very simple task, it gets tedious.

I started searching for batch renaming tools, but everything I found requires a separate program, which I have to specify the parameters each time and it ends up being more time consuming than just clicking and renaming the files manually.

I'm looking for a script or solution which will let me add a button to the Windows 8 Ribbon or Quick Access Toolbar. Ideally I'd like to be able to visit any directory, select one or more items, press the button and have the script rename each file adding "_Final" to the end of the file name.

Comment: so a command-line solution is no use to you?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Lupas Rename utility, here
http://rename.lupasfreeware.org.
It's great for batch renaming of files, or folder, adding to filename (as prefix or suffix), adding to fileextension, autonumbering, and more...
Cheers.